# How to change style of dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, css, smarty

I have a dropdown menu that I just can't figure out how to change...

You can see it by going to http://www.escalatehosting.com/signup and entering any domain name and then selecting to continue after choosing a billing cycle.

On the registration form you'll be able to see the dropdown menu is fancy looking for the "Country" option.  I'm trying to do the same thing for the "State/Region" dropdown but can't figure out what to change...

Here is the code being used for the registration form:

```
<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareafirstname}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.firstname}{else}<input type="text" name="firstname" tabindex="1" style="width:300px;" value="{$clientsdetails.firstname}" />{/if}</td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaaddress1}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.address1}{else}<input type="text" name="address1" tabindex="7" style="width:300px;" value="{$clientsdetails.address1}" />{/if}</td></tr>
<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientarealastname}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.lastname}{else}<input type="text" name="lastname" tabindex="2" style="width:300px;" value="{$clientsdetails.lastname}" />{/if}</td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaaddress2}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.address2}{else}<input type="text" name="address2" tabindex="8" style="width:300px;" value="{$clientsdetails.address2}" />{/if}</td></tr>
<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareacompanyname}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.companyname}{else}<input type="text" name="companyname" tabindex="3" style="width:300px;" value="{$clientsdetails.companyname}" />{/if}</td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareacity}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.city}{else}<input type="text" name="city" tabindex="9" style="width:300px;" value="{$clientsdetails.city}" />{/if}</td></tr>
<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaemail}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.email}{else}<input type="text" name="email" tabindex="4" style="width:300px;" value="{$clientsdetails.email}" />{/if}</td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareastate}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.state}{else}<input type="text" name="state" tabindex="10" style="width:300px;" value="{$clientsdetails.state}" />{/if}</td></tr>
<tr>{if !$loggedin}<td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareapassword}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="password" name="password" tabindex="5" id="newpw" style="width:300px;" value="{$password}" /></td>{else}<td class="fieldlabel"></td><td class="fieldarea"></td>{/if}<td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareapostcode}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.postcode}{else}<input type="text" name="postcode" tabindex="11" style="width:300px;" value="{$clientsdetails.postcode}" />{/if}</td></tr>
<tr>{if !$loggedin}<td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaconfirmpassword}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="password" name="password2" tabindex="6" style="width:300px;" value="{$password2}" /></td>{else}<td class="fieldlabel"></td><td class="fieldarea"></td>{/if}<td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareacountry}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.country}{else}{$clientcountrydropdown|replace:'<select':'<select tabindex="12" style="width:285px;"'}{/if}</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" class="fieldarea">{if !$loggedin}<script language="javascript">showStrengthBar();</script>{/if}</td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaphonenumber}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.phonenumber}{else}<input type="text" name="phonenumber" tabindex="13" style="width:300px;" value="{$clientsdetails.phonenumber}" />{/if}</td></tr>
```

This is the code for the Country drop down that looks how I want:

```
<td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareacountry}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.country}{else}{$clientcountrydropdown|replace:'<select':'<select tabindex="12" style="width:285px;"'}{/if}</td>
```

This is the code that I don't know how to fix for the State dropdown that I don't know how to fix and make it look like the Country dropdown.

```
<td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareastate}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.state}{else}<input type="text" name="state" tabindex="10" style="width:300px;" value="{$clientsdetails.state}" />{/if}</td>
```

Any help with this would be really appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fancy bootstrap theme for your select option can use this [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that the class "selectboxit-text" is not applied to your state dropdown. I'd recommend checking the css file.

Comment: I have actually tried changing it to `select` and it changed the style to how I want but then the dropdown list disappeared and I can't figure out what exactly it should be changed to for the dropdown to still show when using `select`

Comment: What template engine are you using?

Comment: smarty template system

Answer (score 0):

The style of Country selection uses an `ul` and `li`s

Try using this instead of select and input:
`<ul>` with this class -> `class="selectboxit-options dropdown-menu"`

For the first option item in the list:
`<li>` with this class -> `class="selectboxit-option  selectboxit-option-first active"`

For the other items: `<li>` with this class -> `class="selectboxit-option"`

Answer (score 0):

Country drop down is generated from the jQuery, you can use that class in your drop down menu.

Comment: I've tried doing that and the drop down list appeared blank.  What did you change in the line to make it work?

Comment: your select tag should be display:none, and put your all data into span tag, that span tag you have to put all class which are in country.